# SSIS - Fuzzy Lookup Contains

Tags: ssis

I'm preparing a SSIS package that matches a list of keywords against a larger list of descriptions.

For instance
List A:

- Apple
- Banana
- Bought
- Sold

List B:

- I bought an Apple
- I sold a Banana
- Banana is not a pineapple

Result Expected:

1. Apple, I bought an Apple
2. Bought, I bought an Apple
3. Banana, Banana is not a pineapple

When I do fuzzy lookup, the similarity score is way too low. What I could use is a function that looks up based on "Contains". Is there a transformation that could do that?

Comment: For that case you could use the SQL Server `LIKE` keyword. There's nothing fuzzy about that example.

Comment: Given the input of Banana, how would you determine between the two choices that contain Banana (your expected results indicate B3) or can one input yield multiple outputs (A2:B2, A2:B3)?

Comment: The answer is going to be "use a script component" but until we know more about the expected logic, this question is likely too broad to be answerable

Answer (score 0):

*"a function that looks up based on 'Contains'"*

I think you can use a Conditional Split to implement this, the Condition is like: 
FINDSTRING(UPPER(Col2),UPPER(Col1),1) > 0
//Col1 refers to the output from List A, Col2 refers to List B. If it's true the rows will flow to Contains output.